# PHP: skipping a default parameter in a function call

Tags: php

The below is a php function:

> bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )

I would like to call the function, specifying the first and the third parameters, leaving the second default. Can I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php esp. ex #5 and #6

Specifically:

> Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected.

Comment: For user defined functions and methods you can use Syntactic https://github.com/topclaudy/php-syntactic

Answer (score 1):

Make a wrapper function with only the parameters you want to specify.